# Arrays dont get updated in a while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want the arrays to be updated when the loop repeats
like the new values for the user as tickets have been subtracted.
some details
i need them to be for the new user that uses the interfaces the interface ,

while True:
import time

```
#task1
uptime=[9,11,13,15]
uptickets=[480,480,480,480]
upmoney=[0,0,0,0]

downtime=[10,12,14,16]
downtickets=[480,480,480,640]
downmoney=[0,0,0,0]  

print("Welcome")
print("Times for going up are:",uptime)
print("Times for going down are",downtime)
x=0
print ("Tickets remaining per time are=")
for x in range (0,4):

    print (uptime[x], uptickets[x])
    print (downtime[x], downtickets[x])

#task 2
Userup=int(input("Enter time for going up "))
while Userup !=9 and Userup !=11 and Userup !=13 and Userup !=15:
    print("invalid")
    Userup=int(input("Enter time for going up "))

Userdown=int(input("Enter time for going down "))
while (Userdown !=10 and Userdown!=12 and Userdown!=14 and Userdown  !=16) or 
Userdown < Userup:
    print("invalid")
    Userdown=int(input("Enter time for going down "))

#extracting indexes
for count in range(0,4):
    if Userup==uptime[count]:
        upindex=count    
#print(upindex)

for count in range(0,4):
    if Userdown==downtime[count]:
        downindex=count    
#print(downindex)
time.sleep(2)
    #input tickets
num_tickets=int(input("Enter number of tickets "))
while num_tickets > uptickets[upindex] and num_tickets > downtickets[downindex]:
    print("Error. Check availability: Enter number of tickets again")
    num_tickets=int(input("Enter number of tickets "))
#cost calculation
one_cost=25
trip_cost=one_cost*(num_tickets-int(num_tickets/10))
print("cost is",trip_cost)
print("2 way cost is",trip_cost*2)
time.sleep(2)
#updated display

uptickets[upindex]=uptickets[upindex]-num_tickets
downtickets[downindex]=downtickets[downindex]-num_tickets

upmoney[upindex] = upmoney[upindex] + trip_cost
downmoney [downindex] = downmoney [downindex] + trip_cost


for x in range (0,4):
    if uptickets [x] == 0:
        uptickets [x] = str (uptickets[x])
        uptickets [x] = "Closed"
        if downtickets [x] == 0:
            downtickets [x] = str (downtickets[x])
            downtickets [x] = "Closed"
time.sleep(2)
print ("Tickets remaining per time are=")
time.sleep(0.5)
for x in range (0,4):
    print (uptime[x], uptickets[x], upmoney[x])
    print (downtime[x], downtickets[x], downmoney[x])  
#task3
totalpassengers=0
totalmoney=0
up_passenger=[0,0,0,0]
down_passenger=[0,0,0,0]

for x in range(0,3):
    up_passenger[x]=480-uptickets[x]
    print("For time:",uptime[x],"there are",up_passenger[x],"passengers")
    totalpassengers = totalpassengers + up_passenger[x]
up_passenger[3]=480-uptickets[3]
print("For time:",uptime[3],"there are",up_passenger[3],"passengers")
totalpassengers = totalpassengers + up_passenger[3]

for x in range(0,3):  
    down_passenger[x]=480-downtickets[x]
    print("For time:",downtime[x],"there are",down_passenger[x],"passengers")
    totalpassengers = totalpassengers + down_passenger[x]
down_passenger[3]=640-downtickets[3]
print("For time:",downtime[3],"there are",down_passenger[3],"passengers")
totalpassengers = totalpassengers + down_passenger[3]

totalpassengers/=2
totalpassengers=int(totalpassengers)
print ("Total passengers today:", totalpassengers)

for x in range (0,4):
    totalmoney = totalmoney + upmoney[x]
    totalmoney = totalmoney + downmoney[x]

print ("Total Money taken is:", totalmoney)
```

I want the arrays to be updated when the loop repeats
like the new values for the user as tickets have been subtracted.
some details
i need them to be for the new user that uses the interfaces the interface ,

Comment: I recommend to get your code down to a [minimum working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: While it is beneficial to show your work effort, it is counter productive to dump all code.  Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you